# History.Back with refresh

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I would like to have the `History.back();` functionality with a complete refresh of previous page.

Any idea how to do that (and make it work in IE, FF and Chrome).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could redirect (by window.location) to document.referrer

i.e.

```
window.location.href = document.referrer;
```

Internet Explorer fix for passing referrer to a particular location:

```
if(IE){ //IE, bool var, has to be defined
    var newlocation = document.createElement('a');
    newlocation.href = URLtoCall;
    document.body.appendChild(newlocation);
    newlocation.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but does not seem to work in IE8 (FF and chrome OK). document.referrer is empty

Comment: I've just tried it! It works on IE8 too. How do you call the page? If you call it by window.location, in IE you have to do a workaround to make the referrer work properly (I'm going to edit the code above)

Comment: Thanks for update code and suggestions. I'm not sure how the page is called (some SharePoint magic) Can I figure it out from fiddler? Any other ideas to way the document.referrer is empty?

Comment: As far as I know, document.referrer is empty on IE only when the page is called by JS through window.location. (I've just tried and by "firing" the clicking of the a element, it works) Sincerely, I don't know why in your case it's empty. 
Do you use any server side lang? In place of document.referrer you could try to make a server side script that prints and assign the HTTP referrer to a JS var.

Comment: OK, I'll accept this answer as it seems like my problem with document.referrer is related to some IE bug http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem, and going to document.referrer is not equivalent to history.back(). i.e. if you refresh a page, document referer will be the same page, while history.back() will go back correctly.

Comment: As of 2023 this keeps working great!

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the location replace() method:

```
window.location.replace(document.referrer)
```