# refresh the previous page with history.back

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [History.Back with refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657545/history-back-with-refresh)

I have an input button that I have assigned with `onclick="history.back()"` .

Is there a way to use this but force the previous page to be refreshed?
I want it to work in FF and IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you need, here is a fix which needs some more preparation at first, but should work:

1. Place an invisible element with a (serverside created) timestamp in your document.
2. Place an eventlistenener which checks the timestamp and reloads the page if it is too old.

Now when you navigate back to this site, either via your button or the browser's back button, the onload handler will fire, check the date and reload the page if necessary.

client side pseudo code:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load",function(){
    // compare timestamp stored in element with current time and if it is too old,
    // reload page e.g. via document.location.reload()
   var d1 = document.querySelector("#timestamp").innerHTML;
   var d2 = Date.now;
   if (d2-d1 > 10000 ) document.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: @Riju It might be even better (and more appropriate) to place a meta-tag with the time in the head and execute the comparison right away to minimize the delay.